# Can Shadcn ui be installed for Vite + React with javascript and not typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, vite

I am having trouble installing and using [shadcn](https://ui.shadcn.com/) components on mt vite + react + tailwind project. i tried following the guide in their documentation [here](https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/installation/vite). It seems that it requires typescript for it to work?

I tried to:

1. Create a React Javascript project with Vite
2. Install Tailwind for Vite React from their [doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite).
3. Follow the shadcn guide in their docs i linked above.

It says it needs the "tsconfig.json" file, which means typescript. I then tried the steps above again, but instead of javascript i created a Typescript project. But it still did not work, i get this error when i try to run the server with `npm run dev` :
[EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRTDb.png)

I have uploaded the source code on github [here](https://github.com/sulejmanhoxha/shadcn-project-vite)

Comment: The code for most if not all of the components use TypeScript. you can download them and remove the typescript annotations probably (and have less intellisense and such). if you're intent on using javascript, nothings stopping you from setting up a TypeScript project and then using JavaScript for your own stuff (though i highly recommend learning basic TypeScript). as for your error, i would completely delete the project folders you made for this and make a new ts project through vite. make sure you're either on the latest version of node or using the LTS version of node

Comment: @Samathingamajig thanks for your reply! I did create a ts vite project with react and i followed the [docs](https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/installation/vite) and added/installed the button component just to test it but i got this error message. did i configure something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
Should work